# How to remove one pixel border from 9-patch image? Android

Tags: android, nine-patch

I have created a 9-patch image with name.9.png extension by using draw9patch tool. In my app the image stretch accordingly where I have marked the one-pixel border in draw9patch tool but, in my app the one-pixel border is visible with black color. Now how can I remove the one-pixel border from the 9patch image or make the border transparent I mean to invisible the border in my app. Pleas help me in this respect.

You can see my 9-patch image below.

[image]

Comment: How do you display your image?

Comment: now you can see my 9-patch image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 9-patch image is incorrect. Although there can be multiple stretchable areas (black lines on the top and left side of the image), the padding areas (black lines on the bottom and right side of the image) cannot be broken up into multiple sections. See [this guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) for more details.

Also, it looks like you are missing the row of 1 extra pixel at the bottom of the image where you would specify the horizontal padding area. Even if your image doesn't require horizontal padding, you should still include the extra pixel row and leave it empty.

Try this image:

[image]

Comment: Actually, I just realized that you can have multiple stretch/padding areas. So this probably isn't the issue.

Comment: Updated answer: stretchable areas can have multiple black lines, but not the padding areas.

Comment: I still don't get it, it looks like the same image, with the black borders

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking on how to deselect the area you have selected : 
This is how you do it : **hold Shift and click**  will deselect that pixel (or just shift and click+drag for deselect a line)